# Is there an easier way to write an If function where the condition is also the value if true in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

For example, I have a cell that uses an If function and the condition is a long expression (I will just refer to this as "long expression" in my example), if the condition is true it should return the long expression, if false the cell should be blank.

example:

=If(long expression > 0, long expression, "")

Is there a shortcut with the syntax so I don't have to write the long expression twice in the if function without storing the long expression in another cell and referencing it?

Comment: Try to englobe the long expression and IF function using the [LET function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999#:~:text=Excel%20for%20Microsoft%20365%20Excel%20for%20Microsoft%20365,apply%20within%20the%20scope%20of%20the%20LET%20function.). Something like: LET(x,long expression,IF(x,x,"")).

Comment: Can you an example of your long expression?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio, nm, found my mistake and got it to work. Thank you

Comment: based on your title, if you can convert your expression to possibly output an error/na when you want to use `""` then you could `=IFERROR` or `=IFNA`. Otherwise if there is a key component of your long expression that can determine true/false you can use that as your condition.

Answer (score 2):

If your long expression is really long, then I suggest you use [LET function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999#:%7E:text=Excel%20for%20Microsoft%20365%20Excel%20for%20Microsoft%20365,apply%20within%20the%20scope%20of%20the%20LET%20function.) to reduce the length of the formula. As stated [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999#:%7E:text=The%20LET%20function,native%20formula%20syntax.):

> The LET function assigns names to calculation results. This allows storing intermediate calculations, values, or defining names inside a formula. These names only apply within the scope of the LET function. Similar to variables in programming, LET is accomplished through Excel’s native formula syntax.

```
=LET(x,long expression,IF(x,x,""))
```

Let assume that your long expression is: `G5 + H5 + I5 + J5 + K5 + L5 + M5` and you would like to check if the it is more than 10. You can use the `LET` function has shown below:

```
=LET(x,G5 + H5 + I5 + J5 + K5 + L5 + M5,IF(x>10,x,""))
```

instead of:

```
=IF( (G5 + H5 + I5 + J5 + K5 + L5 + M5)>10,G5 + H5 + I5 + J5 + K5 + L5 + M5,"")
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's really that complicated, I'd first calculate the said "long expression" in a column.

This column **will be hidden**, let's say it's column B here.

Then you can simply make in C3: =if(B3>0;B3;"")

*And if memory serves, you can do even easier than if(B3>0;B3;"") while using (specific) numbers format...*